# Amazon S3 upload via Iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, upload, amazon-s3

Sigh, we're back to this. I can easily enough use CORS on any decent enough browser to directly upload files to my AWS S3 bucket. But (it was coming), with IE I have to fall back to Iframes. Easy, set up a hidden Iframe, create a form, set its target to Iframe name/id, submit form. If the upload is successful, the Iframe is redirected to a url I specify and I can access the whatever I need to. But if an error occurs, since the Iframe is now on an AWS domain, I won't have access to the XML content of the error. Infact, I won't even know that an error has occurred.

I've seen brave people on the internet talking about hosting an html file, on the same bucket to  which files are to be uploaded, and then using postMessages to route the Iframe content, or something of that sort.

Could someone please explain to me how to achieve this mythical solution? The jQuery file uploader by Blueimp seems to solve this, but by God the code is so jQueryified that I haven't been able to get the gist of it.

### Editing for clarity

1. IE<10 does not have a FileReader API.
2. Because of 1, I cannot use an XDomainRequest to send a file to S3
3. So use an Iframe and post that along with a complete form to S3
4. If successful, AWS redirects to a page on server, which reads the headers and
   then returns a JSONP style response that can be read by scripts on client (redirect page can
   be specified by me).
5. If on error, all I can do right now is wait for a timeout to expire and then console log
   an IFRAME ID, and popup an alert so that the user can then query for the the iframe by ID,
   read the DAMN XML content, figure out the AWS specified error, and then retry (I'm being sarcastic..)

Comment: Why does CORS not work for IE? I got one using jquery fileupload plugin, but I have not tested it on IE. This post http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/01/10/asynchronous-browser-uploads-to-s3-and-gcs-using-cors-aspnet-mvc seems to indicate that it would work on IE

Comment: @d33pika - it uses the magical jQuery fileupload plugin. I've mentioned in the question that the task of extracting just that much logic out of the plugin is quite very very hard

Comment: @d33pika there is also the issue of NO CORS in IE

Comment: @JibiAbraham: Well, IE has had CORS since version 8, but keeping with tradition, it obviously decided to go its own ways. [XDomainRequest - Restrictions, Limitations and Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

Comment: The basic plugin is not that complicated: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin . Check it out.

Comment: @Henrik I must look at that. Will post in ten minutes

Comment: @d33pika - i meant the implementation, as in the source code, not the actual usage. But thanks anyway

Comment: Also check this out: http://codeartists.com/post/36892733572/how-to-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-your

Comment: @d33pika - That again will not work on IE (the link you posted)

Comment: xhr can work on IE with some exceptions: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Almost everything you need to know about how the jQuery File Upload plugin does iframe uploads is in its [Iframe Transport plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js) (along with supporting [result.html](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/cors/result.html) page).

As an introduction, you may want to read their user instructions on their [Cross domain uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads) wiki page, specifically the **Cross-site iframe transport uploads** section. (Note that according to their [Browser support](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support) page, niceties like upload progress are not supported for IE <10, so I wouldn't consider these possible using the iframe transport, at least without significant effort.)

(Also, I don't believe any S3 upload implementation using the File Upload plugin has access to the XML content of a file upload error)

The Iframe Transport plugin adds a new Ajax "transport" method for jQuery and is not specific to the File Upload plugin. You may want to read the documentation for [jQuery.ajaxTransport()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/) to understand the API that jQuery provides for adding a new transport.

---

I'll try to summarize what the Iframe Transport plugin is doing, and how it relates to uploading files to Amazon S3:

1. When a file upload is triggered, the `send()` function is called. This function:

   - Creates a hidden form element
   - Creates an iframe element with `src="javascript:false;"`, and binds a `load` event handler to the iframe
   - Appends the iframe to the hidden form, and appends the hidden form to the document.
2. When the iframe is created and its "page" loaded, its `load` event handler is called. The handler:

   - Clears itself from the iframe, and binds another `load` event handler
   - Configures the hidden form:

     - The form's `action` will be the URL for the S3 bucket
     - The form's `target` is set to the iframe, so that the server response is loaded in the iframe
     - Other fields, e.g. `AWSAccessKeyId`, are added. Specifically, `success_action_redirect` is set to the URL of [result.html](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/cors/result.html) on your server, e.g. `http://example.org/result.html?%s`.

       Normally, the `%s` token should be replaced with the upload results by server-side code, but with S3 this can be hard-coded with a success value by your code, since Amazon will redirect to this URL only if the upload succeeded.
     - File input fields from the original form are moved into the hidden form, with cloned fields left in the original fields' place
   - Submits the hidden form
   - Moves the file input fields back into the original form, replacing the cloned fields
3. The file(s) are uploaded to S3. If successful, Amazon redirects the iframe to the `success_action_redirect` URL. If not successful, Amazon returns an error, which is also loaded in the iframe.
4. The iframe's `load` event handler is called. The handler:

   - Tries to save a reference to the iframe's `document` object. If the file upload failed, the handler saves an `undefined` instead.
   - Calls the complete callback with a success code and a reference to the iframe's `document` object (or `undefined`)
   - Removes the hidden form (and iframe)
5. Before control is returned to your code, the iframe's `document` object is passed to a converter (at the bottom of the [Iframe Transport plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js#L168)), depending on what type of data you were expecting. The converter extracts that data from the `document` object and returns it (or `undefined` if the file upload failed) to your callback(s).
6. Your callback(s) (`success` and/or `complete` as passed to [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) is called. A success code is always returned by the plugin, and so any `error` callback will not be triggered.

   If the data passed to your callback(s) is the value you included in the `success_action_redirect`, then the file upload succeeded. If the data is `undefined`, then the file upload failed.

---

**Update:** If the error XML page stays on the same origin as the S3 bucket, then another page from the S3 bucket, loaded into another iframe, can access the original iframe's content (because they are from the same origin). Your main page can communicate with this second iframe using `postMessage()` (or [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)'s FlashTransport, if you need to support IE6/7).

Comment: "Tries to save a reference to the iframe's document object" - that would throw an uncatchable error would it not?

Comment: The error is [catchable](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js#L77).

Comment: I'll give this a shot, I've got everything but the error handling down, will let you know, tx

Answer (score 3):

This problem, of providing accurate feedback to users using browsers with no FileReader or FormData support has troubled me a lot as wel. I spent a whole 3 days trying to come up with a solution and finally came up with something close to nothing.

Lets get down to the facts:

- **Browser**: **IE8/9** // thin chance of being any other browser with no FileReader support
- **Upload Behavior**: we need it to be "Ajax" for UX reasons
- **Toolbelt**: [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)*

Ok, then there is no other way of uploading the file than using an iframe. Right?

So, jQuery File Upload using jQuery Iframe Transport as @jeferry_to describes so well is the tool for the job.

*Actually the tool/plugin doesn't change a thing..

What now?

Well... we need to access the S3 response inside the transport iframe. But we can't because its on a different domain. 
So we decide to deal with it by using this trick involving a second iframe.

**The setup:**

- TopFrame, our page (www.myhost.com)
- iframe TransportFrame (s3.amazonaws.com), auto created by the plugin - contains the S3 response
- iframe XDMFrame (s3.amazonaws.com), accesses the TransportFrame when ordered, grabs the response and delivers it to TopFrame

**The scenario:**

First of all we need to modify jQuery Iframe Transport so that it does not auto remove the auto-generated form and transport frame. We need to do this cause #postMessage which will use later is asynchronous by nature and we don't want the iframe gone by the time we try to access it.

1. on TopFrame we upload a file to S3using jQuery File Upload. We now want to make sure it has been uploaded and get the error otherwise.
2. TopFrame sends a cross domain message to XDMFrame using #postMessage, supplying the name of the TransportFrame. This message actually says: 'Hey check the contents of iframe X' and when you do send em back to me.
3. XDMFrame then does something like `top.frames['iframe X'].document.documentElement` to access te contents of the TransportFrame, stringifies them and sends them back to TopFrame through #postMessage.
4. TopFrame receives the message, shows the proper feedback to the user and removes the form and iframe left over because of our jQuery Iframe Transport modification.

Ok, everything should work now cause everything is done by the book.

Nahh, you should not even bother.

You see... if you force a modern browser to use the iframe transport instead of the XHR2 the above solution will indeed work like a charm.

However that's pointless. We want it to work in IE8 + 9.

Well... in IE8/9 it sometimes work, it sometimes doesn't. Usually it doesn't.

Why? Because of the IE's friendly HTTP error messages. Oh yes you read just fine.

In case of an error, S3 responds with an HTTP error status depending on the error (400, 403 etc). Now, depending on the status and the length of the response as shown [here](http://perishablepress.com/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/), IE discards the S3 response and replaces it with a friendly error message. In order to overcome this, you must make sure the response is always > 512 bytes. In this case you cannot guarrantee anything like that cause you don't control the response. S3 does and the typical errors are less than 512 bytes.

**In short:**

The iframe trick works on those browsers that do not need it, and doesn't on those who do.

Unfortunately, I can't think of anything else so that case is closed for me now.

Comment: I really do appreciate you taking the time to respond even after such a long time. The post messages thing is a nifty trick, thank you for sharing. Hopefully there will be many who find its uses :)

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing my answer in the comments: IE has CORS support with some restrictions: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

and this implementation of direct upload to S3 looks much simpler than jquery fileupload and its not in jquery:
http://codeartists.com/post/36892733572/how-to-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-your

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

AS for the "postMessage" scenario, maybe the iframe should contain a simple javascript

[edit] for iframes taken over by an errormessage

> IFRAME script

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
    window.parent.postMessage(document, '*'); //replace '*' with your parent if possible   
}
// just to get the proper document for the parent to target me
window.addEventListener('message',function(e) {
    if (e.domain == 'example.com') { // the domain of your parent frame
        if (e.data == "Salute") {
            window.parent.postMessage("I'm here", '*'); //replace '*' with your parent too
        }
    }
});
```

Now parent knows the iFrame perfectly well and can track it's status (depending on if it's answering a simple postMessage)

> PARENT script

```
var iFrameTarget;
var iFrameTakenOver = false;
var timer;
window.addEventListener('message',function(e) {
    if (e.domain == 'example.com') { // the domain of your iframe
        if (e.data) { // e.data contains the iframe document
            if(typeof(e.data) =='object')
                iFrameTarget = e.source;
            elseif(e.data == "I'm here")
            {
                iFrameTakenOver = false;
            }
            timer =setInterval(call_iFrame(),5000); // check iFrame presence in 5 seconds
        }
    }
});

function call_iFrame() {
    iFrameTarget.postMessage('Salute');
    iFrameTakenOver = true;
}
```

IF iframe is not responding with it's "code" iFrameTakenOver will be permanently set to false checking that will verify if an error has occured or not.

Comment: S3 takes over the frame in the case of an error, unfortunately, I've come to the sad conclusion that IE users most definitely will just have to settle for "Something went wrong" instead of what exactly went wrong

Comment: Oh I see... that's a shame but that means you know if it has been taken over or not, just by sending a postMessage to said iFrame, if you get a reply all is good, if not it has been taken over because of an error...

Comment: @JibiAbraham I updated the script to trace if the iframe has been taken over by S3