# Progress on client side upload directly to S3 trough iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, blueimp

Related questions:

1. [Amazon S3 upload via Iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578512/amazon-s3-upload-via-iframes)
2. [Progress Bar for Iframe File Uploads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480240/progress-bar-for-iframe-file-uploads)

Using [jQuery file upload plugin from Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), my users are uploading files directly from their browsers. Then comes IE8, where the upload plugin uses the hidden iframe method.

I would like to monitor the progress of the upload, however according to [browser support of jQuery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support#upload-progress), this is not possible in IE8, BUT:

I was wondering if one of the following workarounds is possible?

a. The answer for question [2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480240/progress-bar-for-iframe-file-uploads) defines the workaround to querying manually the upload progress, which I could be doing through my application server, however I did not found any option to look up the progress of a current multipart upload on `aws-s3`, (how) is this possible? If there is an `aws-sdk` snippet for that in `ruby` please include!

b. In the comments of question [1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578512/amazon-s3-upload-via-iframes) @d33pika links [HTML5 Rocks - Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) where it is stated that IE8+ is able to do XHR in his own way. Would it be possible to use that and monitor the progress? If it's an option I should be able to extend the [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to use that option for IE8+ that gives me the feeling it's not possible, why wouldn't have been already implemented then?